# regex help, pulling last two verbs seperated by semi-colons

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

```
Verb_1;Verb_6;Verb_7;EXT_80;CAP_81;TREE_26;END;
```

In the example above, I am trying to figure out how to regex out CAP_81, and TREE_26, basically the last two verbs in the string seperated by semi-colons. So the BigQuery SQL field would equal

```
CAP_81;TREE_26;
```

I am not sure how to work regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_extract()`:

```
select regexp_extract(val, '([^;]+;[^;]+;)END;$')
```

Comment: Sorry for the low effort question, but to be honest you saved me like an hour trying to figure it out on my own. So I thank you for that. Reviewing your answer helped me learn more also